# How to make the list of links match the height of the main text and compliment its width?

Tags: html, css

[How my site looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCIbe.png)

It floats higher than the main text, and the contents of the list are just placeholders. Here are the relevant bits of HTML:

```css
p {
  padding: 0 10px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 192, 247, 0.904);
  border: 3px solid lightskyblue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow:  0px 0px 1px black;
}

#intro .introduction {
  width: 80%;
  float: left;
}


#intro .submenu {
  float: right;
  width: auto;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 3px solid lightskyblue;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="intro">
    <div class="introduction">
        <p>
            main text is right here
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="submenu">
       <nav>
           <ul>
              <li ><a class="active" href="index.html">Main page</a></li>
              <li><a href="course.html">Course</a></li>
              <li><a href="content.html">Contact</a></li>
           </ul>
            </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

The list also floats higher than the text for a reason I don't understand. I tried setting intro to `display:table;`, but that didn't work. I'm pretty bad at using HTML and CSS, but I have to do this for a university project, so here I am.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 1):

When you wrap the main text in a *p* tag you add 20 pixels of margin.  Either remove that from the *p* tag or add it to your *nav* tag.

```css
p {
  padding: 0 10px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 192, 247, 0.904);
  border: 3px solid lightskyblue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow:  0px 0px 1px black;
}

#intro{
   display:flex;
   align-items:top;
}

.submenu{
margin:20px;}

.introduction{
width:80%;}


#intro .submenu {

  width: auto;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 3px solid lightskyblue;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="intro">
        <div class="introduction">
            <p>
                main text is right here
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="submenu">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li ><a class="active" href="index.html">Main page</a></li>
                    <li><a href="course.html">Course</a></li>
                    <li><a href="content.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        </div>
```